# What's wrong with my usage of String.EndsWith?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ends-with

I can't figure out why EndsWith is returning false.

I have the C# code:

```
string heading = "yakobusho";
bool test = (heading == "yakobusho");
bool back = heading.EndsWith("​sho");
bool front = heading.StartsWith("yak");
bool other = "yakobusho".EndsWith("sho");
Debug.WriteLine("heading = " + heading);
Debug.WriteLine("test = " + test.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("back = " + back.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("front = " + front.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("other = " + other.ToString());
```

The output is:

```
heading = yakobusho
test = True
back = False
front = True
other = True
```

What is going on with EndsWith?

Comment: Copying this out into [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j3SEY3) highlights the fact that there's a hidden character at the beginning of `"sho"`

Comment: Different characters, possibly a hidden character. There's nothing wrong with `EndsWith()`

Comment: The `"​sho"` string in the third line is 4 characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"​sho"` string in the third line starts with a [zero length space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). `"​sho".Length` returns 4 while `((int)"​sho"[0])` returns 8203, the Unicode value of the zero length space.

You can type it in a string using its hex code, eg  :

```
"\x200Bsho"
```

Annoyingly, that character isn't considered whitespace so it can't be removed with `String.Trim()`.

Answer (score 4):

This contains an invisible character before the "sho" string:

```
bool back = heading.EndsWith("​sho");
```

The corrected line:

```
bool back = heading.EndsWith("sho");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `EndsWith` argument there is a special character.

As you can see from this code:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string heading = "yakobusho";

      string yourText = "​sho";
      bool back = heading.EndsWith(yourText);

      Debug.WriteLine("back = " + back.ToString());
      Debug.WriteLine("yourText length = " + yourText.Length);

      string newText = "sho";
      bool backNew = heading.EndsWith(newText);

      Debug.WriteLine("backNew = " + backNew.ToString());
      Debug.WriteLine("newText length = " + newText.Length);

    }
  }
```

OUTPUT:

```
back = False
yourText length = 4
backNew = True
newText length = 3
```

The length of `yourText` is 4 and so there is some hidden character in this string.

Hope this helps.